# Black halo / ghosting on transparent layered PSD file imported into FCPX

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

In Photoshop, I have prepared a scene to be animated in FCPX. I just selected a part of the clouds and copied into a separate layer, with 10px feather to avoid rough edges. However, when I import the same PSD into FCPX, the feather becomes a black halo. Anyone know how to fix this?
See examples below:
[image: Photoshop]
[image]

Comment: Do the layers maybe use a certain blending mode in Photoshop which is not supported in FCPX?

Answer (score 2):

As Final Cut Pro is not made by Adobe, it does not have the same exact processing engine for dealing with the effects in a PSD.  This appears to be an artifact of the difference in processing between the systems.

To work around this, I would recommend exporting the components as TGA or some similar file format that has alpha support.  Simple alpha blending is far more likely to blend in a predictable manner between applications.

Comment: Thanks AJ. I'm not using any special blend mode in the PS files, so I was just guessing that this problem would happen for many when importing PSD files to FCPX (which is promoted as a new feature). I managed to work around it by exporting layers individually as PNGs, but that's a more cumbersome workflow.